# How do i change the file foreground color in remote host tool - PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I've been using the Material theme, but the file colors for the Remote Host toolwindow is too dark to go through the file names as the green highlight makes it more harder.

Is there a way to configure that?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The color can't be changed unfortunately, it's hardcoded. We’re working on a feature allowing themes customization in IntelliJ Platform. Please follow [IDEA-132299](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132299) to get updates.